# Is there any option to change or set VNC password using command line? (UVNC not tight)

Tags: powershell, vnc

im trying to change VNC password using command line, registry or shat ever.

is there any way ?

im using UltraVNC 1.0.4

thank you!

Comment: The configured password is saved to `ultravncini.html` - which you can edit using plenty of command-line programs (`sed`, `awk`, etc): https://uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-server/69-ultravncini.html

Comment: thanks for a quick replay!
the file i have is ultravnc.ini

can i have more advise regarding converting the pass ?

ex: with power shell - convert to HEX or else.
thanks!